# C# - Random bytes to bool[] ... and back doesn't work?

Tags: c#, algorithm, binary

Just some context on the old problem...
[image: Old version of the question]
So, after some testing, and dozens of breakpoints... my code was broken. *But*, I have rounded it down to be somewhere in this function:

```
        public BigInteger getNum()
        {
            BigInteger rtrnVal = 0;
            int pow = 0;
            foreach (bool b in _arr)
            {
                rtrnVal += (b ? BigInteger.Pow(2, pow) : 0);
                pow++;
            }
            return rtrnVal;
        }
```

And this one...

```
        public numToBin(object n)
        {
            assignType(n); //Check if the type is valid
            BigInteger r = new BigInteger(Convert.ToInt32(n)); //Make sure that the type is valid
            _arr = new List<bool>(); //Refresh the internal array of booleans
            while (r != 0) //While we arent left with 0...
            {
                //if (!first) if (_arr.Last()) r += 1; //If the last one was true, then add one, because we want the ceiling (round up not down)
                _arr.Add(!r.IsEven); //Add to the list
                r = r / 2; //Divide by two... I think this may potentially be 
            }
        }
```

But fixed it! Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!

*BTW the error was when I reversed the list.

Comment: If you know where your problem is (line 123 numToBin(object n) method), then just simplify your question and make it clearer by putting only the code that fails, and more details about the expected results. I'm looking at your method and I don't understand what you are doing.

Comment: Ok

In a moment I'll add commenting.

Comment: Instead of nesting all your method calls in one line, it might be easier to split them out into separate lines, so you can examine the return value of your methods.

Comment: There doesn't appear to be a question here.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
    public BigInteger getNum()
    {
        BigInteger rtrnVal = 0;
        int pow = 0;
        foreach (bool b in _arr)
        {
            rtrnVal += (b ? BigInteger.Pow(2, pow) : 0);
            pow++;
        }
        return rtrnVal;
    }
```

And this one...

```
    public numToBin(object n)
    {
        assignType(n); //Check if the type is valid
        BigInteger r = new BigInteger(Convert.ToInt32(n)); //Make sure that the type is valid
        _arr = new List<bool>(); //Refresh the internal array of booleans
        while (r != 0) //While we arent left with 0...
        {
            //if (!first) if (_arr.Last()) r += 1; //If the last one was true, then add one, because we want the ceiling (round up not down)
            _arr.Add(!r.IsEven); //Add to the list
            r = r / 2; //Divide by two... I think this may potentially be 
        }
    }
```

Are the correct versions of the code.

Comment: There doesn't appear to be an answer here.